# python genetic algorithm found optimum solution

Tags: python, genetic

I explain, I am trying to develop a program to optimize a system based on the parameters it receives. My program will have to vary these parameters to try to find the best possible combination.

here is a code to simplify my problem:

```
parameters=[["toto1","toto2","toto3"],["tutu1","tutu2","tutu3"],["titi1","titi2","titi3"],["tata1","tata2","tata3"]]

def MySysteme(param1,param2,param3,param4):
    result=0

    for i in range(0,len(param1)):
        result+=ord(param1[i])

    for i in range(0,len(param2)):
        result+=ord(param1[i])

    for i in range(0,len(param3)):
        result+=ord(param1[i])

    for i in range(0,len(param4)):
        result+=ord(param1[i])

    return result

print(MySysteme(parameters[0][0],parameters[1][2],parameters[2][2],parameters[3][0]))
print(MySysteme(parameters[1][0],parameters[2][2],parameters[3][2],parameters[0][0]))
print(MySysteme(parameters[3][1],parameters[1][2],parameters[2][2],parameters[0][0]))


#how to find the highest value?
```

I try to (try) find the highest number, without testing all the parameters naively. hence the use of a genetic algorithm. 1 parameter is a list contained in the list parameters, the contents of the list is a varariante of my parameter

knowing that in my function / my system, one should not have 2 times the same parameter, for example this should not happen: print (MySystem (parameters [1] [0], parameters [1] [0])) or this print (MySystem (parameters [2] [1], parameters [2] [0]))

on the other hand the number of parameters is included in 1 and 4 (there can be 1,2,3 or 4 parameters)

To solve my problem here is the data that I consider: Individual: it is a variant of parameter which carries a name ("toto1", "tata3", "toto2 = 12" ... etc.) Population: set of the variants of the parameters fitness : it is the result of the function according to the parameters a circuit: a set of parameters

but unlike the commercial traveler, I have no starting data => that is to say that I do not have GPS coordinates. and it is at this level that I am stuck for the resolution of my problem.

can anyone help me?

edit:

I have been looking some examples of how I could find the points at which a function achieves its maxium using a genetic algorithm approach in Python. I looked at this tutorial
https://lethain.com/genetic-algorithms-cool-name-damn-simple/

my objective is to found the smaller number to "mySysteme" function
i set a new code :
 je re-explique mon probleme plus simplement. J’ai mets un code plus complet, plus clair avec un algo génétique.

```
from random import randint, random
from operator import add
from functools import reduce

parameters=[["toto123","toto27","toto3000"],["tu","tut","tutu378694245"],["t","choicezaert","titi3=78965"],["blabla","2","conjoncture_is_enable"]]

def individual(length, min, max):
    return [ randint(min,max) for x in range(length) ]

def population(count, length, min, max):
    return [ individual(length, min, max) for x in range(count) ]

def fitness(individual, target):
    sum = reduce(add, individual, 0)
    return abs(target-sum)

def grade(pop, target):
    individu_number_parameters=randint(1, len(parameters)-1)
    for j in range(0,individu_number_parameters):
        position=randint(1, len(parameters)-1)
        parameter=parameters[position]
        if isinstance(parameter, list):
            parameter=parameters[position][randint(1, len(parameters[position])-1)]
    result=0

    for i in range(0,len(parameter)):
        result+=ord(parameter[i])
    return result

def evolve(pop, target, retain=0.2, random_select=0.05, mutate=0.01):
    graded = [ (fitness(x, target), x) for x in pop]
    graded = [ x[1] for x in sorted(graded)]
    retain_length = int(len(graded)*retain)
    parents = graded[:retain_length]
    for individual in graded[retain_length:]:
        if random_select > random():
            parents.append(individual)
    for individual in parents:
        if mutate > random():
            pos_to_mutate = randint(0, len(individual)-1)
            individual[pos_to_mutate] = randint(
                min(individual), max(individual))
    parents_length = len(parents)
    desired_length = len(pop) - parents_length
    children = []
    while len(children) < desired_length:
        male = randint(0, parents_length-1)
        female = randint(0, parents_length-1)
        if male != female:
            male = parents[male]
            female = parents[female]
            half = int(len(male) / 2)
            child = male[:half] + female[half:]
            children.append(child)
    parents.extend(children)
    return parents


target = 0
p_count = 100
i_length = 6
i_min = 0
i_max = 100
p = population(p_count, i_length, i_min, i_max)
fitness_history = [grade(p, target),]

for i in range(1000):
    p = evolve(p, target)
    fitness_history.append(grade(p, target))

for datum in fitness_history:
   print(datum)
print(len(fitness_history))
```

I updated with new code. My ask : i want that my program found smaller number

Comment: i didn't understand a thing.. Feynman said something along the lines of *if you can't explain it, you don't understand it*. so please understand it first yourself

Comment: I want to found optimum solution for have the bigger number in my fonction.
With use genetic algorithm

Comment: You can randomly initialize your GA. You haven't really shown any work except specifying the problem, I doubt anyone is going to write the code for the GA for you.

Comment: I updated with new code. My ask : i want that my program found smaller number

Comment: This is starting to look like an iterative process to get someone to write code for you.

Comment: What is the specific coding problem you have?

Comment: my program too seldom returns the best solution (50)